# How to perform a query with a converted value

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple converter to map `DayOfWeek` to an Integer to match the legacy data code which used Calendar day of week values.  However, when I am doing criteria queries, it appears to be using the ordinal value of DayOfWeek rather than my converted value.

```java
    default Optional<ProgramSchedule> findByProgramWeekAndDay(final Program program, int week, final DayOfWeek dayOfWeek) {

        return findOne(((root, query, cb) ->
            cb.and(
                cb.equal(root.get(ProgramSchedule_.program), program),
                cb.equal(root.get(ProgramSchedule_.week), week),
                cb.equal(root.get(ProgramSchedule_.dayOfWeek), dayOfWeek))
        ));

    }
```

And calling it with

```java
programSchedules.findByProgramWeekAndDay(psFdProgram, 1, DayOfWeek.TUESDAY)
```

Gives me the following where parameter 2 was supposed be the day of the week, however, I was expecting it to be `3` which is the day of week value for Calendar.TUESDAY.

```
ype.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder TRACE binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [PS-FD]
ype.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder TRACE binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [1]
```

I'm using Spring JPA

The converter looks like this

```java
@Component
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class DayOfWeekConverter implements AttributeConverter<DayOfWeek, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(final DayOfWeek dayOfWeek) {

        if (dayOfWeek == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (DayOfWeek.SUNDAY == dayOfWeek) {
            return Calendar.SUNDAY;
        } else if (DayOfWeek.MONDAY == dayOfWeek) {
            return Calendar.MONDAY;
        } else if (DayOfWeek.TUESDAY == dayOfWeek) {
            return Calendar.TUESDAY;
        } else if (DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY == dayOfWeek) {
            return Calendar.WEDNESDAY;
        } else if (DayOfWeek.THURSDAY == dayOfWeek) {
            return Calendar.THURSDAY;
        } else if (DayOfWeek.FRIDAY == dayOfWeek) {
            return Calendar.FRIDAY;
        } else if (DayOfWeek.SATURDAY == dayOfWeek) {
            return Calendar.SATURDAY;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public DayOfWeek convertToEntityAttribute(final Integer dbValue) {

        if (dbValue == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (Calendar.SUNDAY == dbValue) {
            return DayOfWeek.SUNDAY;
        } else if (Calendar.MONDAY == dbValue) {
            return DayOfWeek.MONDAY;
        } else if (Calendar.TUESDAY == dbValue) {
            return DayOfWeek.TUESDAY;
        } else if (Calendar.WEDNESDAY == dbValue) {
            return DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY;
        } else if (Calendar.THURSDAY == dbValue) {
            return DayOfWeek.THURSDAY;
        } else if (Calendar.FRIDAY == dbValue) {
            return DayOfWeek.FRIDAY;
        } else if (Calendar.SATURDAY == dbValue) {
            return DayOfWeek.SATURDAY;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("dbValue=%d is not valid", dbValue));
        }
    }
}
```

I annotated dayOfWeek as follows

```java
    @Id
    @Column(name = "Day", nullable = false)
    @Convert(converter = DayOfWeekConverter.class) // I had it without this one as well
    private DayOfWeek dayOfWeek;
```

It's not limited to criteria queries either, it also occurs with JPQL queries:

```
    @Query("from ProgramSchedule p where p.program = :program and week = :week and dayOfWeek = :dayOfWeek")
    Optional<ProgramSchedule> findByProgramWeekAndDay(final Program program, int week, final DayOfWeek dayOfWeek);
```

yields

```
    where
        programsch0_.Program=? 
        and programsch0_.Week=? 
        and programsch0_.Day=?
ype.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder TRACE binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [PS-FD]
ype.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder TRACE binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [1]
ype.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder TRACE binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - [1]
```

Comment: Did you use `@Convert` in your `ProgramSchedule` entity?

Comment: yes tried that as well even mvn clean to see if the code gen made a diff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Id` and `@Convert` cannot be used together, so you have to use an `@IdClass`, like so:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(MyEntity.class)
public class MyId {
  @Id
  private DayOfWeek dayOfWeek;
  ...
}


public class MyEnity implements Serializable {
  @Column(name = "Day")
  @Convert(converter = DayOfWeekConverter.class)
  private DayOfWeek dayOfWeek;
}
```

**EDIT** According to docs the above code also doesn't work, so I looked for a workaround and found this:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
  @EmbeddedId
  private DayOfWeek dayOfWeek;
  ...
}

@Embeddable
public static class Id {
  @Column(name = "Day")
  @Convert(converter = DayOfWeekConverter.class)
  private DayOfWeek dayOfWeek;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if that would work, but according to the specs and https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10594 it shouldn't work.  So what I did was use Integer and just had getters and setters to convert for me.

Thanks though.

Comment: Well, that was always an option. Thanks for checking, now I don't know how to convert an `@Id` field. Is it even possible?

Comment: Not according to the spec and Hibernate may make things break for violating that part of the spec (see the last comment in the bug)

Comment: Ideally it should flag it as a validation error

Comment: I've added a workaround I found on the web, if you're still interested you could check if it works, as I'm not on my computer right now.